# React-Bootstrap not working after npm installing and importing it

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I made an app using `create-react-app` and then I ran `npm install react-bootstrap` and then `npm install bootstrap`

Then in my main `src/index.js` file, I imported Bootstrap as : `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

It still wont work on any components? I tried to add the Alert button in my `app.js`, it imported it successfully but when I added `variant="success"`, it is displaying no colour!

Comment: you can  inspect in dev tools and see if any styles aren't overriding them

Comment: maybe it could work if you import it in App.js file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of this error. i tried running the bootstrap code that didn't work on another react project and it worked fine. i jst fixed this by using the cdn. maybe there was error in the bootstrap node installation
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />` on my public html.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the CDN, so I get rid off those problems before having them. What you have to do is the following:

In your HTML file:
Inside your **head** tag, put this:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And inside your **body** tag, put this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just include `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to your `App.jsx` and all is solved